# how to retrieve data from dynamically created table in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC 4 and I am stuck in a Problem,  I have bound a table dynamically with some data from database as following on cshtml page

```
<table id="tblFeature">
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    Include
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Facilities
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Description
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            @foreach (var feature in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.EditorFor(item => feature.Checked)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(item => feature.Name)
                                    </td>
                                    <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(item => feature.Description, 2, 70, null)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            }
                        </table>
```

Now I want to update the values like ,check or uncheck the checkbox,update the  description in text area etc., in order to achieve that i need to add the updated values in the list in controller class and then I will update those values in database. but i don't know how to achieve that, it is something like following in plain english

```
foreach(feature in tblFeature)
{
    if(feature is checked)
         {
             featureList.add(feature)
         }
}
```

any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change View for correct binding:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Controller"))
    {   
    <table id="tblFeature">
          <tr>
              <th>
                 Include
               </th>
                <th>
                 Facilities
                  </th>
              <th>
             Description
          </th>
        </tr>
         @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
         {
           <tr>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ProductSizeID)
           <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Checked)
            </td>
             ...
              </td>
             </tr>
        <input type="submit"  value="save"/>
        }
```

Post in Controller and save change

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<feature> ViewModels)
    {
     foreach (var feature in ViewModels)
     {
        if(feature.Checked)
        {
         featureList.add(feature)
        }
     }
    }
```